# Word Count spark program is not working on remote master

Tags: apache-spark

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

public class SimpleApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String logFile = "README.md"; // Should be some file on your system
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadooponwindows-master\\hadooponwindows-master");
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("spark://192.168.121.59:7077");
   // SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]");

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache();

    long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("spark"); }
    }).count();

    long numBs =logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("b"); }
    }).count();

    System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);

    sc.stop();
  }
}
```

Above code is not working on remote master.It's giving warning mention below -
TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources.

But if i am running using local master tthen it's working properly.

Comment: Can you provide the spark-submit command?

Comment: spark-submit  --class com.hsc.spark.SimpleApp --master spark://192.168.121.59:7077 /usr/local/src/Spark-Streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: Can you please try this? `spark-submit --class com.hsc.spark.SimpleApp <your application jar file> --master yarn --deploy-mode client --jars /usr/local/src/Spark-Streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-depen‌​dencies.jar`